# Error About Something That has to do With an Array Index Being out of Bounds

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to make code that will automatically generate two sentences randomly, but when I press run, It says:

```
'Hi Exception in thread "main java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 12 out of bounds for length 3 at Main.main(Main.java:25)'
```

I had no idea what to do, and I tried turning the `String[]` into a `Long[]`. I don't think it worked though.

I'm guessing it has to do with the array being long, but anyway, here's my code:

```
class Main {
  public static void (String[] args) {

    int max = 2; //highest random integer. Don't need a minimum.
    int maxtwo = 13;
    
    String[] words = {"Hi", "I", "Do"};
    String[] words2 = {"like to play football", "enjoy math", "like math", "love football", "don't really like math", "think I'm not very cool", "am very hungry", "have lots of trouble on math", "watch lots of TV", "java is cool", "java's awesome", "I love java", "I want pizza"};
    //words2[] prints only if words[1] is selected, not words[0]

    Random gen = new Random(); //variable for the first part of the first sentence

    int wordsRandomSelection = gen.nextInt(max); //randomly selects a value from String[] 
    words

    System.out.print(words[wordsRandomSelection] + " "); //print string[] with a random value

    if (words[wordsRandomSelection] == words[1]) {

      int wordsRandomSecondOutput = gentwo.nextInt(maxtwo);

      System.out.print(words[wordsRandomSecondOutput] + ".");
    
    }
  }
}
```

Can you please show me what the error is?

Comment: The info you need is right there in the error message. You have an index of 12 being used with an actual length of 3. You index into `words` with a random number using `maxtwo`; couldn't that be it?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the error occurs on this line:

```
      System.out.print(words[wordsRandomSecondOutput] + ".");
```

`words` only have 3 elements, while the generated random from `maxtwo` has 13 as max.

Maybe you intended to have `words2` on that print statement instead of `words` but you accidentally reversed it. a little careless mistake.